# Sending an Email through gmail SMTP Server (SSL)

Tags: c#, email

I know there's a lot of example on how to send an email using C# but I am really running into some issues and I can't make it to work.

I always get `"Failure sending mail"` error, `Unable to connect to the remote server - No connection could be made because the active machine actively refused it (IP address here)`.

What does this error mean? And how do I fix this?

Any help will be much appreciated

Here's the code that I've been using: (although I already did try a lot of things)

```
string SendersAddress = "test@gmail.com";
string ReceiversAddress = "test1@gmail.com";
const string SendersPassword = "test-pass-here";
const string subject = "Testing";
const string body = "Hi This Is my Mail From Gmail";
try
{
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
            Port = 587,
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(SendersAddress, SendersPassword),
            Timeout = 3000
        };
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage(SendersAddress, ReceiversAddress, subject, body);
    smtp.Send(message);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: If the machine actively refused it, then you know the server exists but is rejecting your connection. Sounds like you've got a wrong port number or wrong server.

Comment: It *looks* like there's no SMTP service running on your mail server, but unless you clarify how exactly you're trying to send mail (some code would of course also be welcome), your question will be very hard to answer.

Comment: I already edited the post to contain the code I'm currently using. Thanks guys :)

Comment: Did you get this figured out? I'm very curious what your problem ended up being.

Comment: No I haven't. I actually gotten busy and will most likely work on it again sometime this month.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're running into issues connecting to the SMTP server.

Make sure the firewall is open on port 25, and that you actually have an SMTP server running wherever you're trying to establish your connection.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to establish an SSL connection to [gmail](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=13287) on port `587`. That port must be used with TLS, not SSL.

Use port `465` instead.

Also note that the [Timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.timeout.aspx) property is expressed in milliseconds, so `3000` can be a little short, depending on your network. Try using a more permissive value, like `30000`.

Comment: Now it's giving me "Operation has timed out"

Comment: @Jerald, yup, a 3-second timeout probably does not make it. Answer updated accordingly.

Comment: even if I set the Timeout property to 30000-50000 still giving me the same error..

Comment: @Jerald, does `smtp.gmail.com` reply to pings from your machine?

Comment: @Jerald, that's strange, I can telnet into `smtp.gmail.com` on port `465` without any timeout problem. Can you try that? If it fails, then maybe gmail has temporarily banned your IP because it grew tired of receiving your SSL packets on its TLS port ;)

Comment: "TELNET smtp.gmail.com 465" and it's working.. its jus't in C#. this is frustrating haha

Answer (score 1):

Also worth checking that your anti-virus is not blocking port 25, I have been caught by that before!

Answer (score 0):

Same for me in past few days,

Easy solution:

First check if everything is OK with `Telnet`, then try to do the same in C#.
  Here is a good intro : http://www.wikihow.com/Send-Email-Using-Telnet.

Just beware that some servers use the `EHLO` command instead of `HELO`

EDIT:

take a look at the way that you can connect to SMTP server of Google [here](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=78775)